# Open a sql server database for large un-LDF'ed operations?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm going to perform a lot of update / delete / insert operations on mssql server 2005/8

however , I want to speed those operations by **NOT** writing to the log files. ( ldf)

I believe this will imperove performnance( for my current case)

How can I open the DB without writing any data to the LDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable transaction logging for these operations. SQL Server always logs enough to rollback statements in the event of error or a crash.

All you can do is reduce it by choosing simple recovery model.

Comment: Hi. If i choose `simple recovery model` will it cancel my ldf's ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - No idea what you mean by "cancel my ldf's". Simple just means that operations that can be minimally logged will be and the log file will potentially need to grow less. Putting your DB into simple will break your backup chain though (if you have one)